# How to interop with TAutoIntfObject object from a TWebBrowser control?

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

I'm having a `TWebBrowser` control which implements `IDocHostUIHandler` to extend the control of a JavaScript interop through the `IDispatch` container. This works fine, except that I don't know, how to dispatch event from JavaScript back to the web browser control.

The extension object is a container based on `TAutoIntfObject` like in [`this example`](http://www.delphidabbler.com/articles?article=22&part=5#case-study-extdef). As you can see in the example, there is no interop with the web browser control. Ideally, I'd like to implement events on that extension object, but I don't know how to properly declare the `TAutoIntfObject` object in my web browser control. Let's say I'm having this extension object:

```
type
  TZoomChangeEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; ZoomLevel: Integer) of object;
  TOpenLayersExt = class(TAutoIntfObject, IOpenLayers)
  private
    FOnZoomChange: TZoomChangeEvent;
    // the ZoomChange method is invoked from JavaScript
    procedure ZoomChange(ZoomLevel: Integer); safecall;
  public
    property OnZoomChange: TZoomChangeEvent read FOnZoomChange write FOnZoomChange;
  end;

implementation

procedure TOpenLayersExt.ZoomChange(ZoomLevel: Integer);
begin
  if Assigned(FOnZoomChange) then
    FOnZoomChange(Self, ZoomLevel);
end;
```

And a `TWebBrowser` control like this:

```
type
  TMapBrowser = class(TWebBrowser, IDocHostUIHandler)
  private
    // the extension object
    FExtObj: TOpenLayersExt;
    // IDocHostUIHandler::GetExternal method
    function GetExternal(out ppDispatch: IDispatch): HRESULT; stdcall;
    // this is the TOpenLayersExt.OnZoomChange event method implementation
    procedure OnZoomChange(Sender: TObject; Zoom: Integer);
  public
    // ordinary constructor
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

implementation

constructor TMapBrowser.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  // create extension object
  FExtObj := TOpenLayersExt.Create;
  // here the event method is properly binded; if I'd change the FExtObj type
  // to IDispatch with TOpenLayersExt(FExtObj) typecast, it wouldn't
  FExtObj.OnZoomChange := OnZoomChange;
end;

function TMapBrowser.GetExternal(out ppDispatch: IDispatch): HRESULT;
begin
  // the problem is that I don't know how to properly pass this object to the
  // ppDispatch parameter; if this GetExternal method is called second time,
  // the FExtObj seems to be released, but I don't get why
  ppDispatch := FExtObj as IDispatch;
  Result := S_OK;
end;
```

The problem is that if I declare the `FExtObj` object as `TOpenLayersExt`, the event method is binded but the `FExtObj` object reference seems to be released after the first extension object method invoke (from JavaScript).

If I declare it as `IDispatch`, the reference is not released after the JavaScript function invoke, but the `OnZoomChange` event is not binded.

It's hard to post the full code here as it's composed from more parts, [`here is a complete project`](https://code.google.com/p/projects-stackoverflow-tlama/downloads/detail?name=15971871.zip) made in Delphi 7.

So my question is, how to consume events from `TAutoIntfObject` extension object in a web browser control; how to declare the extension object, so I'll be able to handle events from a web browser control and pass it to the `IDocHostUIHandler::GetExternal` method parameter still keeping the interface object reference ?

Comment: I suppose you saw this article? : http://www.delphidabbler.com/articles?article=22&part=3. They use an external container via IOleClientSite.

Comment: Or checkout the sourcecode from EmbeddedWB...

Comment: @whosrdaddy, that's where I originated my code (even linked in my question), but I don't know [`how the IOleClientSite`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/188015/en-us) comes into play there. Whenever you call a method from JavaScript through `external`, the `IDocHostUIHandler::GetExternal` method asks for an external object, which must have a dispatch method of the name you're calling. There's no need for `IOleClientSite` here. About EWB, how does it help me ? There's just a `OnGetExternal` event in which you're passing the extension container, but that's what I actually have.

Comment: I'm not so sure what you need. the [example](http://www.delphidabbler.com/articles?article=22&part=1) you linked to worked perfectly for me (as oposed to the *lame* EmbeddedWB implementation).  Look at the sources: `TExternalContainer = class(TNulWBContainer, IDocHostUIHandler, IOleClientSite)` and in the main project `fContainer := TExternalContainer.Create(WebBrowser1);`. It's kinda tricky but actually a very good idea to avoid an interposer class like you did : `TMapBrowser = class(TWebBrowser, IDocHostUIHandler)`.

Comment: And yes, IE will dispose of FExtObj interface object when it is no longer needed. this is by design.

Comment: I once did something like the opposite: getting to the container from an ActiveX loaded in a web-page: http://yoy.be/item.asp?i98 that's where IOleClientSite comes in. I should find some time though to dig into the code you post here, looks very much like things I've done as well.

Comment: @kobik, there's no problem with my implementation if I declare `FExtObj` as `IDispatch`. But then I can't use `OnZoomChange` event. On the other hand, if I declare `FExtObj` as `TOpenLayersExt`, I can use events, but the reference is released. The question might be interpreted also as why the `FExtObj` reference is not released if it's declared as `IDispatch` and is released when it's `TAutoIntfObject` (sorry, I'm quite newbie in this). And yes, you're right that *interposer* class is not the best for this.

Comment: Have you tried declaring `TOpenLayersExt = class(TAutoIntfObject, IOpenLayers, IDispatch)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use reference counting, ie. keep FExtObj as a reference to an interface, rather than object:

```
  private
    // the extension object
    FExtObj: IDispatch;
```

...

```
constructor TMapBrowser.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
var
  AExtObj: TOpenLayersExt;
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  // create extension object
  AExtObj := TOpenLayersExt.Create;
  AExtObj.OnZoomChange := OnZoomChange;
  FExtObj := AExtObj as IDispatch;
end;

destructor TMapBrowser.Destroy;
begin
  FExtObj := nil;
  inherited Destroy;
end;
```

Comment: I confirm, fixing the ref-counting resolves the issue. If you're in for a minimalist fix, insert `FExtObj._AddRef;` at line 140

Comment: @Stijn, just like MS shown in [`their example`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/188015/en-us). TOndrej, thanks! This works fine as well.

Comment: @Stijn, I've finally used this solution since it seems that IE release the references irregularly and if I tried to use `_AddRef` their count was never decreased. Thanks anyway!